# A question about superconductor from path integral

Tags: path-integral, superconductivity

In the Altland (page277), He defined the Gorkov Green's function in path integral and then integrate out fermion field.

We know the gaussian integral is like $\int exp(-\bar\phi A \phi)=constant* det(A)$. However, in his notation, before the variable is a positive sign. How could gaussian integral be applied in that way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minus sign doesn't matter, because you're dealing with Grassmann variables ($\Psi$ describes the fermionic degrees of freedom.) As such, the Gaussian (Grassmann) integral always converges.

Therefore, simply applying the formula $\int d(\bar{\phi}\phi)\exp(-\bar{\phi}^T A \phi) = \det(A)$, the integral over the $\Psi$ degrees of freedoms simply gives $\det(-\mathcal{G}^{-1})$. In fact, it should actually be $\det(-\beta \mathcal{G}^{-1})$, so that the argument of the determinant is unitless. In many papers (and even Altland and Simons' textbook when they evaluate the $\Psi$ integral later on!), you don't see the minus sign or the factor of $\beta$, since it (surprisingly) doesn't affect much. In many calculations, this factor of $-\beta$ just cancels.

You can see this, for example, in Chapter 4 of Altland and Simons, where they evaluate the free energy of a noninteracting Fermi gas in the path integral formulation. There, they end up deriving the Fermi gas partition function to be $Z = \det[\beta(-i\hat{\omega}+\hat{H}-\mu \hat{N})^{-1}]$. If you recall that $G = i\hat{\omega}-\hat{H}+\mu \hat{N}$, then we can rewrite $Z = \det[-\beta G]$, i.e. it has the same $-\beta$ factor as in the fancier superconducting case above. Now, how does this $-\beta$ factor disappear? Well, in practice you care about $F$, not $Z$. When you calculate $F = -T \log(Z)$, the $\log(Z)$ term becomes a Matsubara sum. When the sum is evaluated via contour integration, you eventually end up with a difference that goes as $\ln(-\beta x) - \ln(-\beta y)$ for some $x$ and $y$ (see Altland Chapter 4 for details.) In this difference, it is obvious that the $-\beta$'s disappear.